# Attention Layer in TensorFlow 2: I get "TypeError: 'AdditiveAttention' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, tensorflow, attention-model, tensorflow2

I got an error with `AdditiveAttention()` layers (i.e. **Bahdanau** Attention) in TensorFlow 2 that I don't fully understand. I want to train a chatbot with a seq2seq attentional model trained on two `Question` and `Answer` datasets.

My problem is represented by an error I get when I try to add the Attention layer to the model. This is my build function:

```
def build_model():
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, AdditiveAttention, Dense
    
    # Input: get char embeddings
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(200), name='encoder_inputs')
    encoder_embedding = Embedding(60, 200, name='encoder_embedding')(encoder_inputs)
    
    # LSTM Encoder receives Question - returns states
    encoder_lstm = LSTM(units=64, return_state=True, name='encoder_lstm')
    encoder_outputs, h, c = encoder_lstm(encoder_embedding)
    encoder_states = [h, c]
    
    # Bahdanau Attention
    context_vector, attention_weights = AdditiveAttention([h, encoder_outputs])
    
    # Decoder Embedding layer receives Answer as input (teacher forcing)
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name='decoder_inputs')
    decoder_embedding = Embedding(60, 200, name='decoder_embedding')(decoder_inputs)
    
    concat = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), decoder_embedding], axis=-1)

    # Decoder LSTM layer is set with Encoder LSTM's states as initial state
    decoder_lstm = LSTM(units=64, return_state=True, return_sequences=True, name='decoder_lstm')
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(concat) 
    
    decoder_dense = Dense(units=60, activation='softmax', name='decoder_dense')
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

    chatbot = Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs=[decoder_outputs]) 
    return chatbot
```

When I run the function with:

```
bot = build_model()
```

I get the following error:

> `TypeError: 'AdditiveAttention' object is not iterable`

Can someone help me understand the error, and make a correct implementation of an Attentional seq2seq model?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem this week. It seems that the tf.keras Additive attention does not return the attention weights, only the context vector.

Therefore you just need to eliminate "attention_weights" when calling AdditiveAttention() and you should be good.